# Is every vector bundle a tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

We know every tangent bundles is orientable and have even dimension. I think these properties are not sufficient to a vector bunble be (isomorphic) to a tangent one. I want to find some geometric/topological property, which is only satisfied by tangent bundle to formulate something like:

*Let $E$ a $2n$-dimensional orientable manifold that can be realised as the total space of some vector bundle over a manifold $M$. If (some condition), then $E$ can also be realised as a tangent bundle.*

I'm trying to get some feeling about vector bundle based on the tangent one.

---

Edit: the comments show me it's not a precise question. Ok, let's change a little bit: Fixed a manifold $M$, I want to characterize $TM$ in the follow sense: in what conditions a VB $E$ over $M$ is (isomorphic to) the tangent one and I can formulate:

*Let $M$ be a manifold and $E$ be orientable $2n-$dimensional VB of $M$. If (some conditions over $E$), then $E$ is VB-isomorphic to $TM$, $E \simeq TM$.*

I want, at least, a thinner necessary condition to $E \simeq TM$.

Comment: I think your initial question has a certain flaw. Vector bundle is a manifold (or scheme) along with a specific map, satisfying a bunch of good local properties. Of course all this comes along with an underlying base space over which all the above can happen. Your question makes no sense to me. You can probably come up with something more specific, because the obvious answer is "no" since tangent bundles is a very specific class of vector bundles.

Comment: I doubt this question makes sense; it seems you want to consider vector bundles over a fixed (necessarily even dimensional) manifold which is isomorphic to the tangent bundle of the base manifold, and as it is stated there is only one such vector bundle. If you want to see if there exists only one vector bundle over any even dimenisonal manifold, then it is obviously false.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with your statement? In order to have a vector bundle, you need a manifold as base space, and it is not necessarily the case that the vector bundle in question is the tangent bundle.

Comment: Is it reasonable now?

Comment: @ThadeuHenriqueCosta Obviously not every bundle is tangent. It seems to me that you are asking about some "characteristic properties" of tangent bundles, how they are different from other bundles. Then it would be a very broad and soft question and I don't think there is any simple answer. Look at the spheres, for instance -- tangent bundles of $S^1$, $S^3$ and $S^7$ are trivial, but the others are increasingly complicated. Let's see if someone else offers some insight...

Comment: I want to characterize tangent bunbles, but i don't think it's really readable by me now. Anyway, I would like to have thinner criterion to say that some vector bunbles are not tangent.

Comment: In that case, there can be some restrictions a vector bundle being the tangent bundle. The dimension is one such as you already mentioned, and the existence of Wu classes can play a role.

Comment: I understand the question as: "let $E$ be a $2n$-dimensional orientable manifold, $M$ a $n$-dimensional manifold, and $E \to M$ a vector bundle. Is it true that $E \cong TM$ as vector bundles?" Is that it?

Comment: As Peter pointed, it'll depend heavily on $M$.

Comment: @IvoTerek why is that? If $E \to M$ is a vector bundle with dimension $2n$ then the fibers have dimension $n$. Just take any isomorphism from each $E_{p}$ to $T_{p}M$ and you have the charts in $p$ inducing basis on $E_{p}$. All the constructions of $TM$ basically are just vector bundles over $M$ with the right dimension with basis induced on the fibers by the charts. Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: @Capim An isomorphism of vector bundles is a diffeomorphism between the total spaces that happens to be a linear isomorphism between fibers; indeed you can pick linear isomorphism from each $E_p$ to $T_pM$ but they might not glue well together to form a diffeomorphism between $E$ and $TM$. One possible obstruction is non-orientability of $E$. In other words, I understood the question as "is there a set of conditions ensuring that we can glue convenient linear isomorphisms together?"

Comment: @IvoTerek This [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6a367jv9p9ilth/lang.PNG?dl=0) is Proposition 3, page 44, from Lang's Differential Manifolds. The condition VB Mor 2 he is talking about is always true for finite dimension. Can it be used for this?

Comment: @Capim No, nothing wrong, of course. That proposition gives us a VB-morphism alright, but nothing seems to ensure that the map between (the total spaces of) $\pi$ and $\pi'$ (following Lang's notation) is a diffeomorphism. The proposition only gives smoothness, as far as I see, at least.

Comment: @IvoTerek If you take the base map to be the identity and the maps on the fibers to be isomorphisms, then the fiber map is a bijection and the proposition guarantees smoothness from both the map and inverse doesn't it?

Comment: @Capim The fiber map will be a bijection, yes, but I still can't see how smoothness of the inverse follows. And I think it does not...

Comment: Here is another possible interpretation of this question, an edited version of the current 2nd paragraph which differs somewhat from the interpretation of @IvoTerek. "Let $K$ be a $2n$-dimensional orientable manifold such that there exists a vector bundle $E \mapsto M$ and a diffeomorphism $K \mapsto E$. What condition on $K$ is sufficient to ensure the existence of a manifold $N$ and a diffeomorphism $K \mapsto TN$?"

Comment: Oh, I was a little lazy when I wrote the question and it's not precise. Sorry. The ideia is: E is a VB of  M and I want to know if it's the  tangent one. Something like a caracterization of the tangent bundle of a fixed manifold. I will edit to make it precise (?).

Comment: I haven't read the book, but this feels like the kind of question one might understand better after reading *Characteristic Classes* by Milnor and Stasheff.

Comment: I like Ivo Terek's question much better and, in its stable form it is actually quite deep and much of the higher dimensional topology is built around it: Which sphere bundles $S\to M$ (where $M$ is a topological manifold or even a Poincare complex) are isomorphic to stable normal sphere  bundles of $M$? The primary obstruction comes from the null-homotopy requirement for the corresponding map $M\to B/O$; Wall has a secondary, surgery obstruction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_normal_bundle